# Trouble in generating an iterative Menu

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

My goal is to create a menu for the Attendance Module. I want two pieces of information from the user, the student's section and the section number. For eg his section can be A and the section number can be 3. My program cannot proceed unless both these values entered are correct. So I decided to create a menu which will keep on running until the correct data is not entered.

Note:- The variable dummy is an object of class Student, whose methods I'm using to check whether the data entered is Valid or not. If you think that the error has some connection to these methods, then please tell me. I'll make an edit.

```
System.out.println("Welcome to the Attendance Module");
     int str=0;
     String f="";
     Student dummy=new Student();
     int flag=1;
     while(flag==1)
     {
         System.out.println("Please enter the section whose Attendance you would like to mark:A,B,C or D");
     System.out.println("Note that Input is case sensitive");
     f=bw.readLine();
     if(dummy.valid_section(f))// If the input of the section by the user is Valid
     {  
         System.out.println("Enter the Section number");//Can be 1,2,3,4 or 5
         str=Integer.parseInt(bw.readLine());
         if(dummy.valid_stream(str))// If the input of the section number by the user is Valid
          {  flag=0;
               break; //Both inputs are correct
            }
            else 
            flag=1;  // When the Section is correct but the Section number is incorrect
        }

        else
        {System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please try again by pressing 1. Otherwise,press 0 to quit");
           flag=Integer.parseInt(bw.readLine());
        }
    }
```

When I run this program, the loop does not terminate. I don't understand why? I have put the break statements and changed the value of flag wherever required.

As suggested by a User, I've included the two methods of the class Student that are called in this program. They are given below:

```
class Student
{ // Some code...

boolean valid_form(String x)
{  
if((x.equals("A"))||(x.equals("B"))|(x.equals("C"))||(x.equals("D")))
     { return true;
    }
    else 
    return false;
}
boolean valid_stream(int n)
{ if(stream>=1&&stream<=5)
    { return true;
    }
    else 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If you properly indent your code, you would find the issue yourself.

Comment: I've spent a lot of time on debugging, please help!

Comment: What language is this. Please add a tag for the language.

Comment: If dummy.valid_section(f) returns the first time, this will look forever,

Comment: So should I put a break statement at the end of the if statement?

Comment: Can we see the `Student` class

Comment: Yeah! I'll make the edit.